# People don't answer questions, they just comment about how the question can be avoided altogether

Tags: discussion, comments, xy-problem

People don't answer questions, they just comment about how the question can be avoided altogether. This is very frustrating for me as I am an inexperienced programmer and I ask the question to learn how to fix my programming, not to abandon it altogether without learning WHY it is bad.

Comment: The goal of Stack Overflow is **not** to answer **your** questions.  It is to be a repository of good programming questions & answers that all programmers might find useful.  If your problem is localized to you because you are trying to hammer a nail with a screw driver, then a comment pointing to a instructions on how to use a hammer can be more valuable than directly answering the question.

Comment: That is what comments are for. If you know something that does not directly answer the question, but may likely still be of use for the questioner *or anyone else with a similar problem*, add a comment. That way the question still shows up as unanswered, and even if the questioner does not directly benefit, perhaps the advice applies o the next person with a similar problem. **This does not prevent anyone from actually answering the question**

Comment: The best advice to inexperienced programmers is "No, you're going down a rabbit hole.  Don't spend ten hours trying to do it that way, us experienced programmers just do it this way.  Done."  We'd be dicks if we just let you waste your time on BS tasks.

Comment: Well, that still makes us dicks.  Can't win.

Comment: No, the best advice is to actually answer the fucking question that was asked, asshole. You don't know what's best for other people.

Answer (score 19):

Well, that's actually what makes SO great. People try to resolve your problem, not to answer your question. See [What is a XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Agreed. It's usually far more educational to learn why what you're attempting is wrong and what you should be doing instead, than to simply be told how to do your wrong thing.

Comment: What makes it shitty and useless, you mean.

Answer (score 17):

A good way to prevent attempts to help you circumvent your problem is to preempt those comments.  This is good practice in general: Whenever you ask a question, try to predict what people may comment on that question, and then *preemptively answer those comments* in advance.

Say you want to hammer a screw, and want to avoid people suggesting a screwdriver. Include in your question *that you are aware of screwdrivers*; ideally add some references to other questions dealing with screwdrivers for this purpose and a brief summary of the drawbacks of using a hammer; and then emphasize that in this particular case you really do want to use a hammer *anyway*.

This way the potential answerers are aware that you know about the alternatives, so there is no need to point them out to you. And since you included references and warnings, future readers of your question will be aware of the alternative approaches too, so there is no need to add further comments for *their* benefit.

If after that you still get comments suggesting screwdrivers, flag them as "*not constructive*" or "*too chatty*", so that they are removed by a moderator.

---

Now, *if you already have a question* that is attracting comments suggesting alternative solutions, it is not too late: Incorporate the content of these comments into your question, so your question lists all the common alternatives, and highlight that none of these alternatives fit your needs. Then flag the comments as "*obsolete*" and they should be removed.

This may sound like a lot of work, but you will get better and more focused answers this way. And as an additional benefit, editing the question this way will bump it back to the top of the homepage, letting more potential answerers see it.

Comment: Spot on. It can't be overemphasized that just "Don't tell me to use a screwdriver" is not enough; you've got to be able to defend -- at least a little bit -- your desire to use a hammer.

Comment: This also explains when you should stop hammering screws—namely, if you can't make a case for it. Upvoted.

Comment: No, you don't need to be able to defend anything. Answer the question that was asked or get off the site.