# How can I word a question so I can get a straight forward answer?

Tags: discussion

Many times on StackOverflow I have asked a direct question but get comments or answers that avoid the actual question and focus too much on picking out other faults with my code that are totally irrelavant.

For example:

[What is the correct way to call an async method from synchronous code, and block until the task is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794340/what-is-the-correct-way-to-call-an-async-method-from-synchronous-code-and-block)

I started off by asking a simple question, but get loads of comments about it's an anti-pattern and how I shouldn't be creating wrappers around async methods. Quite frankly I don't give a damn... I just want a clear answer to my specific, direct question.

I then updated the question with a real-world example to show exactly why I'm trying to do this... to try to mitigate some of these irrelevant comments (not that it has any bearing on my original question), and try to focus on my question, but this resulted in even more unhelpful comments.

In future, how can I stop these people from trying to pick fault with the design, achitecture and patterns of my example code when all I want is a straight forward answer, to a straight forward question?

I know people are giving up their valuable time to try to help me, and I don't want to seem ungrateful, but it would save everyone's time if they concentrated on answering the question.

Comment: How bad an idea do I have to think something is before I can give a non-straight answer? Many people in [tag:python] ask how to access global variables - should I tell them, or suggest that they refactor to remove global state? As you say, *"people are giving up their valuable time to try to help"* - if you haven't given enough information as to **why** literally no other option is viable, they will (generally!) suggest what they see as better alternatives. I think that's OK! They might help some future visitor with a similar problem. See also e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51178/248731

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Thanks... but I did try to word it in such a way that I hoped would steer it towards a stright answer, I always do now as I've come to expect it with SO... but it didn't work, and it's frustrating. Thanks for the link... that somes up exactly how I feel!

Comment: Closely related: [People don't answer questions, they just comment about how the question can be avoided](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280652) and [What is the best way to deal with toxic/unhelpful comments?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260396)

Comment: You can't.  If someone wants to point out you're doing something wrong, you can't stop them.  You should probably listen to them, or figure it out on your own, if you can't handle it.

Comment: @user1228 Why are you such a miserable cunt?

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten some good information by listening to answers that are effectively, "You also have this other unstated problem..." I don't want that instead of the answer to my direct question but "in addition to" is still quite valuable. I also don't want to restrict these "what you don't know you don't know" responses to people who also have the answer to my original question because they may not have that particular answer.

But you didn't ask about that. ;-) You asked how to get a straight forward answer. One thing you can do is strip down your example code to the bare essentials to isolate the problem in question so there are less side issues to shoot at. You can also ask a very clear question at the beginning (like you did in this post). If the answer can't begin with "Do this:", it probably isn't a clear question.

Comment: And if you are aware of it being in general a *bad idea*, preempt any comments in that direction by a) acknowledging and explaining (in as much depth as seems indicate) why that is, and b) explaining (as thorough as neccessary to acceptably justify) why that horrible thing is something you really have to do anyway.