# Understanding pattern of responders bypassing the actual question

Tags: discussion

I can't tell you how many Q/As I've seen of the form:

```
Q: When I do this, I get this result. Why?
A: Don't do this, do that.
```

or the related comment:

```
C: What problem are you trying to solve?
```

I can understand someone saying "I don't know, but ...", but implicitly blowing off the question seems rude/odd and often misses an opportunity to educate. And yet the behavior seems fairly widely accepted.

Can anyone shed light on this phenomenon? Is this a function of how folks view SO (e.g. as place solely for "solving real problems" vs. more generally a place for "getting questions answered")? Are there more general cultural factors that explain this?

Ironically, this question has been marked as duplicate of [What can I do about posters that derail the question with a discussion about best practices?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267153/what-can-i-do-about-posters-that-derail-the-question-with-a-discussion-about-bes) and [How can I word a question so I can get a straight forward answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291080/how-can-i-word-a-question-so-i-can-get-a-straight-forward-answer), so I will attempt to explain why I see this question as being different:

Both of those questions are asking "how to achieve something" and the answers talk to that. I am not asking how to obtain a direct answer. The assumption that this is the objective of my question seems very similar to the assumptions being made by people bypassing questions. I am trying to understand *why* people respond as they do. It is true that the answers to the other questions touch on responder motivations, and that is certainly relevant, but my question here seems substantially different.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. Sometimes, after the thousandth *"why doesn't my regex for parsing HTML work?"* or *"how do I interpolate values into my SQL query string?"*, you get fed up.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143940/248731, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179567/248731, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280652/3001761, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260396/3001761, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267153/3001761

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that you are referring to questions which simply have multiple solutions to the same problem where one is not necessarily better than the other, but people choose to bypass the solution of the question and offer an alternative anyway? As in: without good reason?

Comment: Most of the time your proposed question and answer form is really more like:

`Q: When I do [something convolutedly terrible], I get this [bad] result. Why?`    `A: Don't do [that terrible thing].  Instead use this [best practice], which was designed to avoid this terrible situation in the first place.`

Comment: often the comments are geared to tease out the Y problem and/or modify the question so that a good answer to the *real* problem can be posted.

Comment: When someone asks you how to drive a nail using a glass bottle without getting cuts on their hand the correct answer is "go get/buy a hammer" not "wear really thick gloves".  The latter answer, despite being a technically correct answer to the stated question, is *actively harmful* to anyone following that advice.

Comment: @Servy While I think questions about bad practices are a subset of this phenomenon, I think they are by no means the dominant case. And even in the example you cited, it doesn't explain why people ignore the question entirely (i.e. fail to explicitly state they are not going to answer the question and why). Also, your example involves a "how" question, which implies a desire to address some underlying need/problem. I'm mostly interested in this phenomenon as it relates "why" questions, the most common example being "Why do I get this error message?"

Answer (score 16):

Some people here would like to believe that software engineering is a profession, with professional standards. When they read a question which makes their eyes bleed due to horrible practice, they try to fix it.

This is justified by the oft-stated goal: to build a permanent repository of professional questions and answers. When some new person searches, it is argued that they should not just find an answer telling them how to do a more efficient job of shooting their own toes off, but rather one explaining how to avoid injury altogether.

Some people, whether through essential crankiness or the stress of constant exposure to horrible sights, deliver their criticisms of the original question and stop there. (Keep in mind that this is the internet, the home of more trolls than Nordic Mythology.) If you post a question here, you have to be prepared to get good answers, bad answers, non-answers, and grand pianos emerging from black holes. Other people have supplied a host of links to prior discussions of this. If you think that an answer fails to offer any way forward for the OP other than a shift to potato farming, feel free to downvote it.

Comment: In all fairness, sometimes the specifications *require* that you shoot your toes off.

Comment: @Louis: I typed up an answer to that here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267159

Comment: @Deduplicator I was being sarcastic with that earlier comment.

Comment: @Louis: Well, this channels compression is a bit too lossy, so I didn't get the hint. Maybe I'll get the next one...

Comment: 'requirement to shoot your toes off' AKA 'my prof told us not to use [best practice] and my question is actually a badly-disguised homework dump'.

Comment: @bmargulies Thank you for taking the time to respond. Your response seems to address why someone might offer advice or ask about underlying problems and why they would not JUST answer the question, but doesn't seem to address why the responder wouldn't even acknowledge the actual question, let alone state that they weren't going to respond to it or state why they weren't going to respond to it. Did I misunderstand your response?

Comment: Edited to add more thought.

Comment: @bmargulies I see the added text about "some people are cranky or under stress", but then you go on to talk about "a way forward for the OP" as if I was trying to figure out how to help OPs. I was/am not. I'm simply trying to understand this community norm that I think is rather odd (i.e. that ignoring questions is acceptable or even commendable). I have no other underlying objective and no problem to solve. My sense is that other Q/A sites seem not to have so much of this bias (e.g. Quora). Perhaps its an "engineer/male" thing. And, as I said, even closing this as a dup shows that bias.

Comment: If you only want to know my view of 'why', you can stop reading at the point where I started to comment on what action you might take.